# Removing heavy green algae in old metal

Tags: cleaning

I have a Ninja gadget I kept in the attic by soaking it with water and salt for about 20 years.

How can I remove all the heavy green Algae deposit? It is green Algae, right?

How does the Algae got stuck to the metal (isn't it permanent bonding), and how where does the Algae come from?

[image: ,]

Comment: why was it soaking in salty water for 20 years?

Comment: To avoid insects from touching it. I forgot to wrap it and seal it.

Comment: Any idea what metal(s) it is made of?

Comment: ...insects don't damage metal...

Comment: @Ecnerwal Except: [How would the anatomy of a metal-eating bug work out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137754/how-would-the-anatomy-of-a-metal-eating-bug-work-out)

Answer (score 3):

It is not algae. It's corrosion, or "patina" though soaking it in salt water leans closer to corrosion, while patina is either naturally acquired through time and weathering or artificially done quickly with chemicals to simulate the natural aged/weathered appearance.

In comments, the object is described as part of a collection, and precious. The proper approach to that is to take it to a metal object conservator (in the museum trade.) They will have experience in preserving the details of objects and safe removal methods.

Since further comment indicates an intention to go ahead and clean it yourself:

Dissolving salt in vinegar is one approach to "home chemical dip" cleaning.

Dissolving salt and baking soda in water and providing a piece of aluminum foil in the container is another "home chemical dip", more commonly used for removing tarnish on silver.

Heat will accelerate both of the above. Boiling vinegar is likely to produce too many fumes if not done outside. Boiling baking soda or salt and baking soda is likely to be fine, but use a non-reactive pot with aluminum foil (and the object to be cleaned) in it. Using an aluminum pot may damage or destroy the pot. Merely warm in a plastic bucket may be simpler to arrange.

Electrolysis (using a low voltage DC power supply) is another approach (I'm more familiar with it for removing rust from iron, but the principle will be similar.) I know that the museum conservator approach to *that* process is far more slow and careful than me trying to get the rust off a pair of pliers I found on the side of a road. I do know that it works well (but slowly) on heavily corroded objects.

Any of the processes will take quite a bit of time to remove corrosion that's been building for 20 years. But if you leave the object in them too long you may damage it more than it has already been damaged by corrosion. If the object is made of two or more different kinds of metal, one type of metal in the object may damage another type of metal elsewhere using these methods. Which is one more reason to consider professional conservation...

Comment: How do you know it is not algae? And how to remove it, whatever it is?

Comment: Becasue it looks exactly like green copper oxides, there is copper or copper aloy showing,  and unless your attic is remarkably well lit the typicial attic darkness does not grow algae. Removal methods would depend on the value of the object and the precise materials - if it's cheap junk, and solid copper or bronze, hot salty vinegar might do a fine job. I wouldn't attempt that with a valuable relic, or without having a pretty good idea that the item was not made of multiple types of metal.

Comment: It's a collection so precious. How do I know what kind of metal it is? It doesn't look like cooper because the color is not cooper, the unexposed part gives the true color of it underneath.

Comment: Then you should take it to a conservator of precious metal things, who will probably be as befuddled by why you put it into salty water for 20 years as we are. The color showing in the middle is absolutely copper or a copper alloy (bronze, or brass)

Comment: Let's just say I forgot about it when I put it in the sealed container with salt and water. Yes I think it's cooper, I tried to remove the green with blade but the green is too sticky. Is there any chemical I can use so the green separates from the remaining cooper?

Comment: I already mentioned hot salty vinegar. I also mentioned that this may be a poor idea with an object you describe as "precious" - a metal object conservator (in the museum trade) may have better/safer for the metal object choices. Electrolysis in another approach (I'm more familiar with it for removing rust form iron, but the principle will be similar) but I know that the museum conservator approach to that process is far more slow and careful than me trying to get the rust off a pair of pliers I found on the side of a road, for good reasons. At least salty water is a known problem (shipwrecks)

Comment: Thanks. I think i will just clean it with hot salty vinegar. Last question, what if I soak it in the hot salty vinegar for 30 minutes or so? This is because there are many edges, it is not possible to manually clean with cloth (with vinegar) all surfaces of it.

Comment: It is one of the most algae and mold  free things in your home as copper kills most stuff. Copper, brass , bronze  or a small chance of a ringer - German Silver , which is brass with several per cent nickel in it to turn it silver.

Comment: Scraping will **not** work. Or rather, if it does work (e.g., you use a blade harder than the core metal of this object) you will be scraping away the details. The chemical treatments work via chemical reactions. One catch though is that if you have the **wrong** chemical reaction you will actually dissolve the whole thing. [Great idea if you **want** to do that](https://www.npr.org/sections/krulwich/2011/10/03/140815154/dissolve-my-nobel-prize-fast-a-true-story) but not if you don't.

Comment: I thought using vinegar with salt will scrap the green stuff automatically without using blade? If it can't do that. Then I'll go to the chemical treatment pathway. I hope someone can make another Answer of how to do the chemical treatments, thanks.

Comment: @Jtl Honestly, if this is as "precious" as you're saying, spend a few bucks and have someone do it for you. We did the same thing when we found a copy of a newspaper reporting the shooting of Lincoln in my wife's grandmother's possessions. It's worth it for something of actual value (or even just sentimental value) to have someone with _experience_ and _knowledge_ do the work. You (or I with the paper) just don't have the right knowledge and risk damaging/destroying something of value to the community. If it's just personal sentimental value, then it's only yourself you're impacting go for it.

Comment: Additionally, considering that all the info you asked in the comments was already included in the answer provided, yet you had to ask again, I'm not sure you'll get the knowledge quickly enough to prevent doing damage to this "precious" artifact.

Comment: Ok. But the Jewelry repair and cleaning service told me they only serviced gold, silver, diamonds and not cooper or brass which are not at all jewelry. So I'm afraid they will use the chemicals for gold and silver on the cooper, Will it be compatible? I don't know of any museum guys who do this. In my country. We barely have museums, or the guys not knowledgeable in all this.

Comment: Is it really cooper oxide or verdigris?  Why no one mentions Diluted hydrochloric acid? I read it won't touch the copper itself and it will definitely dissolve verdigris.

Comment: I have tried the hot salty vinegar. Only  20% are removed. To remove the rest of the patino or vertigris, would it be ok to soak in Hydrocholoric acid (HCL)? You can  answer by adding it in your Answer. Tnx